# React v15.3.2 and react-bootstrap v0.30.6 -- Unknown prop `increment` on <button> tag

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
import React from 'react';
import render from 'react-dom';
import {Button, ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Chat extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.localHandleClick = this.localHandleClick.bind(this);
    }

    localHandleClick() {
        console.log(this.props.increment);
        // this.props.localHandleClick(this.props.increment);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>It Works!</h1>
                <p>This React project just works including
                    <span >module</span>
                </p>
                <p>Global bootstrap css import works too as you can see on the following button.</p>
                <div>
                    <ButtonToolbar>
                        <Button increment={1} bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.localHandleClick}>1</Button>
                        <Button increment={5} bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.localHandleClick}>5</Button>
                        <Button increment={10} bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.localHandleClick}>10</Button>
                        <Button increment={100} bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.localHandleClick}>100</Button>
                    </ButtonToolbar>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have a code snippet like this where `{Button}` is imported from `react-bootstrap`
Now I am getting the error below -

[image]

I went through this url --

https://gist.github.com/jimfb/d99e0678e9da715ccf6454961ef04d1b

But I am unable to understand how to implement this in my code. At least with regard to my component mentioned above. I am pretty new to React development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-bootstrap `<Button />` component is just a wrapper around a regular `<button />` element. What they do is spread all props that are passed in onto the `<button />` element. Since increment is not a HTML property of `<button />` react throws a warning.

You could solve the problem this way:

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.localHandleClick.bind(this, 1)}>1</Button>
<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.localHandleClick.bind(this, 5)}>5</Button>
<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.localHandleClick.bind(this, 10)}>10</Button>
<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.localHandleClick.bind(this, 100)}>100</Button>
```

Which will get rid of the warning and will bind the increment value to the function itself.

Another option is making an `<Incrementer />` component that takes the increment in as a prop and has its own button component and onClick function that just use the prop that the `<Incrementer />` component received to gets its label and value.

for the second example here is a basical codepen for illustration purposes http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/BQNEBL

Comment: I understood how you implemented that . But question is can we not do that with the react bootstrap buttons ? I can definitely do that with a normal button + bootstrap css . But how to do with some components like button of react-bootstrap

Comment: Instead of using an increment property you could also just use `value={incrementValue}` and then change `localHandleClick` function like this: 

`localHandleClick(e) { 
  console.log(e.target.value) // will be your increment value
`
 
and button would just need to be `<Button value={1} // other props here />` just change vlaue for each one

Comment: So this step is by design that anything that is non-html props should not be allowed . Since this spreads across all child elements . And also since the button is just wrapper we a re just left with valid html attributes to be used only for `<Button />` tag . Am I right ?

Comment: Correct, but more so its about knowing what the third-party library is actually doing with the props you pass in. The react-bootstrap library almost always takes all the props passed in and add it to the return HTML element.

Comment: But in my case it doesn't seem to be doing so ?

Comment: It is doing that, but react will check every prop passed into an html element and make sure they are valid properties for that element, if they aren't it throws that warning.

Answer (score 0):

React-bootstrap Button component doesn't seem to have an *increment* prop. The component may be passing such props to underlying html elements. So react is warning you about ununderstandable prop.

But it won't prevent you running the app as it is only a warning